# Rails Test to Confirm Column Updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I am using Minitest and have a controller like this:

```
  def update
    authorize @flag
    respond_to do |format|
      if @flag.update(flag_params)
        format.html { redirect_to flags_path , success: "#{@flag.name} was successfully updated." }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        # format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

I have a JS remote select that triggers a form submit and then returns a DataTable update.  Works fine in development etc.  I commented out the format for the else to force a `no format` error if the update fails.

Here is my test:

```
  test "should assign flag" do
    assert_changes 'flags(:one).assigned_id' do
      patch flag_url flags(:one), format: :js, params: { flag: { assigned_id: users(:operator).id } }
    end
  end
```

The `asssigned_id` is nil for `flags(:one)` and all the patch does it update that column to the id from a user fixture.  Yet my test fails:

```
 FAIL FlagsControllerTest#test_should_assign_flag (44.56s)
        "flags(:one).assigned_id" didn't change
        test/controllers/flags_controller_test.rb:38:in `block in <class:FlagsControllerTest>'
```

Yet this passes:

```
patch flag_url @flag, format: :js, params: { flag: { assigned_id: users(:operator).id } }
assert_response :success
```

Also this fails:

```
assert flags(:one).assigned_id_changed?
```

I have double checked my tests / code and don't think I am missing anything here.

Have I missed something obvious or perhaps I am not applying the assertions correctly?

**UPDATED INFO FOR ANSWER**

Here is my updated model test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class FlagTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :flags
  let(:flag_one) { flags(:one) }
end
```

and controller test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class FlagsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should assign flag" do
    assert_changes 'flag_one.assigned_id' do
      patch flag_url flag_one, format: :js, params: { flag: { assigned_id: users(:operator).id } }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Think the issue is that when you call the fixture directly in code like so...

```
assert_changes 'flags(:one).assigned_id' do
  patch flag_url flags(:one), format: :js, params: { flag: { assigned_id: users(:operator).id } }
end
```

..the test reloads the instance from the fixture and of course it is unchanged.  I've never written a test with a fixture reference inline. What I usually do is set up a **let** using the value from the fixture...

```
class FlagTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :flags

  let(:a_flag){flags(:one)}
```

and then use that in my tests.

```
  test "should assign flag" do
    assert_changes 'a_flag.assigned_id' do
      patch flag_url a_flag, format: :js, params: { flag: { assigned_id: users(:operator).id } }
    end
  end
```

Saves some typing if you have a number of tests, and should fix your issue.

Comment: I tried that in the set-up and after the test `do` block - fail with NoMethodError: undefined method `let'

Comment: just belongs in the test class -- updated answer https://mattsears.com/articles/2011/12/10/minitest-quick-reference/

Comment: My app is running Rails 5.x - this still fails.  Is this for Rails 6?  I added the `let` to my model test and that failed with the same undefined method error.

Comment: This stuff was available in Rails 3.  You said you were using minitest, yes?

Comment: Yes - I must be missing something here - going to double check.

Comment: what does your test_helper look like? and you have this at the top of your test file? require 'test_helper'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232618/discussion-between-dan-tappin-and-dbugger).